# Mongoose TypeError: Question is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

There are lots of questions on stack overflow on this error. But their solutions don't seem to work for me. So I have finally decided to post my own question. (this has probably got to do with my lack of knowledge of javascript/node/mongoose)

My modules are -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var OptionSchema = new Schema({
    option_text: {type: String, required: true},
    is_correct: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false}
});

var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    question_text: {type: String, required: true},
    subText: {type: String, required: true},
    type: {type: String, required: true},
    difficulty: {type: String, required: true, default: 'Easy'},
    status: {type: String, required: true, default: 'Private'},
    options_required: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false},
    explanation: {type: [String], required: true},
    created_by: {type: String, required: true, default: 'Anonymous'},
    created_at: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now()},
    options: [OptionSchema]
});



// Export the model
module.exports.Question = QuestionSchema;
module.exports.Option = OptionSchema;
```

My controller has this -

```
//create
exports.question_create = function (req, res, next) {
    let qu = new Question(
        {
            question_text: req.body.question_text,
            subText: req.body.subText,
            type: req.body.type,
            difficulty: req.body.difficulty,
            status: req.body.status,
            options_required: req.body.options_required,
            explanation: req.body.explanation,
            created_by: '',
            created_at: Date.now(),
            option: req.body.option
        }
    );

    qu.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next('some error occurred ' + err);
        }
        res.send('question Created successfully')
    })
};
```

The closest question I could find is on this link -
[Mongoose TypeError: User is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774997/mongoose-typeerror-user-is-not-a-constructor)

But the answer didn't work.

_/\_

Comment: You need to create model from schema

Comment: @iofjuupasli how is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something along these lines:

```
module.exports.Question = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get that issue when I try to create a new question. :(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a new instance of your schema instead of your model. Only your model has a constructor not your schema. This is due to the fact that you did not export your model but your schema instead. Need to do this:

```
// Export the model
module.exports.Question = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
module.exports.Option = mongoose.model('Option', OptionSchema);
```

Then you can import the models in your controller:

```
var Question = require('./models/question');
var Option = require('./models/option');
```

Assuming your models are in the `models` folder.

Comment: I tried this but I still get that issue when I try to create a new question. :(